# Comparing two columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

This should be quick and easy.

I want to compare two columns and flag any mismatches in a third column. What is the easiest way?

Sample output:

```
1   |      A          B       C
2   |  =========  =========  ===
3   |  apple      apple       
4   |  banana     bananas     1
5   |  orange     orange
6   |  melon      melon
7   |  lemon      lEmon       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does this look like a homework-assignment? ... /tease.  Try something like:

```
=A1=B1
```

for your formula.   This will return true/false, which may not be what you want 100%... but it's the most efficient method.  Alternatively, you can rely on the `IF` statement... to get exact results... like this:

```
=IF(A1=B1,"1","")
```

`IF` is not very CPU efficient... but it'l do the job.  If you need a case-sensitive check... use the `EXACT` function instead.  i.e.

```
=EXACT(A1,B1)
```

or

```
=IF(EXACT(A1,B1),"1","")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) Not a homework assignment, just a quickie on Excel (I am a PHP guy and was gonna write a quick script to process this, but I knew there had to be a super simple way to do it. Thanks for the comprehensive answer!).